# Install my own Open Route Service Machine and setup in my Leaflet

Tags: service, server, routes, leaflet

I searched for a while and I found lots of old (deprecated?) answers on the internet. What is the proper way to install my own Open Route Service Machine server in one of my personal computers?

I'm trying to create my own server because I need a free alternative to https://router.project-osrm.org/, since this website is not stable. I also found this service https://openrouteservice.org/, but didnt find a proper way to apply it in 2020.

Comment: Are you just looking for https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/#quick-start ?

Comment: This part will definitely be useful;) [Disk-and-Memory-Requirements](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Disk-and-Memory-Requirements)

Comment: Do I need 175 GB RAM to run the server? I'll never be able to reach that. =-/